# `require': no such file to load -- v8/init (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working with ruby on rails. I found above error while starting server (i.e rails server).If anyone knows then plz tell me

Comment: I think `v8/init` is from the `therubyracer` gem. Is the gem properly installed?

Comment: Can you add the details of Gemfile to the question?

Answer (score 3):

Please install

```
gem 'therubyracer'

bundle install
```

restart the server

Answer (score 0):

gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.19' -- --with-system-v8